# Converting raw scriptPubKey to readable format

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, debugging

I am debugging Bitcoin cpp code. I wanted to see what exactly come for `scriptPubKey` property of output. Theoretically, I know this but I want to see in the code how does it looks like.

Now while debugging I see  `scriptPubKey` object which is of type `CScript` and hence the format is different which is unreadable (see the screen shot below, it looks like char[]). How to read this value?[image]

It looks like this : 

`\200\002\0\0à\210¼XUU\0\0\220»ÿÿÿ\177\0\0à¡·XUU\0`

Comment: Why do you think there is a human readable form of a bitcoin script tape?

Comment: Try using hex encoding, then you can see what each byte value represents: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script

Comment: @JBaczuk thanks man, you are right I had to get the HEX of it and then call rpc decodescript to get in human readable format. :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

setps:

1. Get the `transactionID`
2. RPCCall `getRawTransaction transactionID` - copy the rawTransaction
3. RPCCall `decoderawtransaction rawTransaction` - copy the scriptPubKey
4. RPCCall `decodescript scriptPubKey`